# javascript images array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

i'm trying to loop through all images on the page, should be easy but i can't see where im going wrong here. the imgs gets populated with the images but the imgs.length returns 0; its somethign stupid but i just cant figure it out.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
console.log(imgs);
console.log(imgs.length);

if(imgs != null){
    //console.log('in loop');
    for(i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
        console.log(imgs.item(i).src);
    }
}
```

Comment: When does this code run?

Comment: `if(imgs != null){` is incorrect; `imgs` will always be an array, but it just might be empty. Change it to `if(imgs.length){`. This won't solve your problem, but just for future reference.

Comment: thanks i'll check that out, figured it out, i was calling it in a script at the top before images are loaded, just changed it to call onload of body and it works. the codes for a bookmarklet so shouldn't matter but just wasn't working in testing. sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {

 var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');// or document.images;

 console.log(imgs.length);

 if(imgs.length > 0){
    for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
        console.log(imgs[i].src);
    }
 }
};
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     console.log($('imgs').length);

     $('imgs').each(function(i, img){
            console.log(img.src);
     });
});
```

Comment: Kudos for including "plain ol' JS" first.  If you're going to show the jQuery equivalent for kicks, then why not update the entire function body to take advantage?  `$('img').each(function(index, img) { console.log(img.src); });`

Answer (score 1):

As Nick says, the script should be runned after the images are loaded. If the script's in the header it won't work as the images aren't loaded yet.